# Hadoop MapReduce intermediate output

Tags: logging, hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a way to output to log the intermediate (Map Phase) output of a MapReduce Job without editing the Application? (The application is not mine, but the cluster is, and I can setup the Hadoop Cluster as I want to)

Comment: Can you re-configure the job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[keep.task.files.pattern](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToDebugMapReducePrograms) parameter can be used to keep the intermediate files. The intermediate files have to be manually cleaned up once the Job has been completed. Since, this is a map/reduce task property, it has to be set in the configuration file and the jar file packaged again.

Comment: can you please elaborate? I've set this parameter, and searched everywhere in the output dirs, and in the mapred local caches, but no map-stage output anywhere...

Comment: ...I got my hopes high on the ${mapred.output.dir}/_temporary, but all I could find there is the reduce "_attempt_local_0003_r_000000" folder, never its "m" counterpart

Comment: I have set the `keep.task.files.pattern` to `.*00000.*` in the `mapred-site.xml` and in the `core-site.xml` the parameter `hadoop.tmp.dir` is set to `$HADOOP_HOME\tmp` . After executing the job, file.out and file.out.index are in the `$HADOOP_HOME/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/praveensripati/jobcache/job_201111031937_0001/attempt_201111031937_0001_m_000001_0/output` folder. These files are in the SequenceFile format. [Here](http://goo.gl/7fJzT) is the sample code for reading the sequence files. What pattern have you used?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the MR framework provides any configuration to save intermediate map output files. Even if such a flag exists, it is not very useful because:

The intermediate output produced by the Maps can't be easily read/used as:
1) Key Value output is serialized before writing to intermediate files.
2) Metadata related to Key Value pairs (Key Length, Value Length, Partition#) is also written to these files (this metadata is in binary format)

An example location of these intermediate files are:
a) Intermediate Intermediate file (Spill output): /yarn/nm/usercache/root/appcache/application_1525687099554_0008/attempt_1525687099554_0008_m_000000_0_spill_0.out
b) Final Intermediate file (Merge Output): 
 /yarn/nm/usercache/root/appcache/application_1525687099554_0008/output/attempt_1525687099554_0008_m_000001_0/file.out