# How to keep mapper intermediate files in Hadoop

Tags: xml, hadoop

Is there a way to keep map intermediate files?

I use the property `keep.files.task.pattern` and set the value to `*.*` in `mapred-site.xml`, but still there are no intermediate files present. How can I fix this?

Comment: This problem has been already solved in this [StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867608/hadoop-mapreduce-intermediate-output)

Comment: one another way to make number of reducers zero and run map-reduce. You will get map output in HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

From [Hadoop MapReduce intermediate output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867608/hadoop-mapreduce-intermediate-output)

> I have set the keep.task.files.pattern to .*00000.* in the
>   mapred-site.xml and in the core-site.xml the parameter hadoop.tmp.dir
>   is set to $HADOOP_HOME\tmp . After executing the job, file.out and
>   file.out.index are in the
>   $HADOOP_HOME/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/praveensripati/job‌​cache/job_2011110319‌​37_0001/attempt_2011‌​11031937_0001_m_0000‌​01_0/output
>   folder. These files are in the SequenceFile format.